# Cannot find jquery file in Angular 9 when include the Jquery file manually

Tags: jquery, angular, angular9

I tried to add jquery library file to assets folder and I added the directory to scripts in angular.json but when I run `ng serve` Angular told me Jquery library does not exist and I am using angular version 9.
I don't know where the problem any help please.

This the error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Script file assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js does not exist.
```

angular.json file:

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
"HorsesClubFrontend": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {},
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/HorsesClubFrontend",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js",
          "assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "assets/js/popper.min.js"]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "HorsesClubFrontend:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "HorsesClubFrontend:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "HorsesClubFrontend:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "tsconfig.app.json",
          "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "HorsesClubFrontend:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "HorsesClubFrontend:serve:production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}},
     "defaultProject": "HorsesClubFrontend"
}
```

assets folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add jquery in angular have to follow below steps.

Step-1

> Add jquery file in **index.html** file into the head tag

```js
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Step-2

> Also need to install two npm packages

```js
npm i jquery@3.5.1 
npm i @types/jquery
```

Step-3

> Add jquery into **angular.json** file into the **script** array

```js
"scripts":  [  
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

Try above steps, I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer your way it's worked, But I found other way by install bootstrap directly `npm install bootstrap --save` and include the libraries to angular.json:

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

and its worked perfectly

Comment: glad to hear that :-)